# Mapping that mixes recursive and non-recursive behavior

Tags: key-bindings

I'd like to define a mapping that performs a "recursively" defined behavior (e.g. uses a `<Plug>` target) followed by a non-recursively defined behavior. For example, using the [camelcase motion](https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion) plugin, I want to move forward a camelcase word and then enter insert mode. Neither of these work:

```
nmap -w <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_wi
nnoremap -w <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_wi
```

Because the `i` needs to be done non-recursively and `<Plug>CamelCaseMotion_w` needs to be done recursively. What's the best way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by introducing your own `nore` map:

```
nnoremap <plug>(my-i) i
nmap -w <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_w<plug>(my-i)
```